# How to display an image in a given position

Tags: c#, winforms, image, picturebox

I have a ball image with 20 pixels width and 20 pixels height.

I want to show it on the PictureBox according to a given (x,y) position.

How can I achieve this? I don't know how to begin with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graphics.DrawImage Method gives you all kind of possibilities to draw a given Image into a pictureBox. You can define Positions and Rectangles inside the Image and/or Picturebox as you like. See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage(v=vs.80).aspx

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the padding option to display the image in the desired position like this:

```
pictureBox.Padding = new Padding(10, 10, 10, 10);
```